# Do invading monsters increase the number of rewards in guild quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

The amount of rewards you receive at the end of guild quests is determined by [a complicated points system](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/762804-monster-hunter-4-ultimate/71733152), where each monster has a certain number of points, and killing more difficult monsters gives you more points, which means more rewards.

This is the reason why quests involving rajang and deviljho are so popular, because they are both worth the most points for any non-elder dragon monster (and so you can pair them with something else, unlike with elder dragons which are always solo).

However, in guild quests that only have one monster (and have one invading "slot"), **does the invading monster affect this point total?** That is, if you kill a velocidrome (which normally gives very few rewards), but a deviljho invades and you kill it, will you get any extra guild quest rewards outside of the usual stuff you get from carving?

(By "rewards" in guild quests, I'm referring to things like relic weapons and armor, not the normal carves.)

Comment: You'll never get weapons or armors as a reward, only stuff to craft them. From my personnal experience in the previous games of the series though, you'll earn extra carves from the Deviljho (in your example) as a bonus reward for killing it, even if the initial quest was to kill a Velocidrome. It still isn't an optimal way of farming as you'll get less loot than if you directly did the Deviljho quest. (I haven't played MH4 though so I'll let someone more experimented with the game confirm or infirm this claim.)

Comment: "You'll never get weapons or armors as a reward" - Yeah, if you haven't played MH4, then this question won't make sense to you. Guild quests in MH4U give out randomly generated armors and weapons (the "relic" system), the best of which are better than anything you can craft.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I thought relics were like charms. I found ["The left monster in a dual quest determines the skin. Each monster contributes their own loot. As an example. A solo Velocidrome pretty much gives crap, and only has a 5% chance to drop a beshackled weapon. (...) But pair it with a Rajang and now your loot will be more like what a rajang drops."](http://www.capcom-unity.com/monster_hunter/go/thread/view/146585/30427337/guild-quests-relic-equipment-basic-info) ; so it sounds like the relic is determined only from the monsters mentioned in the quest.

Comment: Yeah, and my question is whether or not that rajang has to be mentioned in the quest description for it to count, or if just killing an invading rajang gives the same result.

Comment: Well, easiest way to find out is to eat for Gamechanger :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : Yes

Long answer : When in guild quest or exploration with unstable enviroment there is the probability of a invading monster, not only that but in the same quest you can be invaded multiple times (max 5),

any monster you slain during these invades not only give you more points at the end of the quest but also you get some loot in the quest rewards related to the monster you killed.